# slicing keras Variable custom objective function

Tags: theano, keras

I've been trying to implement a custom objective function in Keras (the negative log likelihood of the normal distribution)

Keras expects one argument for the ground truth tensor, and one for the predictions tensor; for y_pred,I'm passing a tensor that should represent a nx2 matrix where the first column is the mean of the distribution, and the second the precision.

My problem is that I haven't been able to get a clear idea how I properly slice y_pred before passing it into the likelihood function without yielding the error

```
'Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function on a (possibly shared) variable instead of a numeric array?'
```

While I understand that I'm feeding l_func arguments of the variable type when it expects an array,I don't seem to be able to grok how to properly split the input y_pred variable into its mean and precision components to plug into the likelihood function.  Here are some attempts; if someone could enlighten me about how to proceed, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
def log_likelihood(y_true,y_pred):
    mu = T.vector('mu')
    beta = T.vector('beta')
    x=T.vector('x')
    likelihood = .5*(beta*(x-mu)**2)-T.log(beta/(2*np.pi))
    l_func = function([mu,beta,x], likelihood)
    return(l_func(y_pred[:,0],y_pred[:,1],y_true))



def log_likelihood(y_true,y_pred):
    likelihood = .5*(y_pred[:,1]*(y_true-y_pred[:,0])**2)-T.log(y_pred[:,1]/(2*np.pi))
    l_func = function([y_true,y_pred], likelihood)
    return(l_func(y_true,y_pred))

def log_likelihood(y_true,y_pred):
    mu=y_pred[:,0]
    beta=y_pred[:,1]
    x=y_true
    mu_function=function([y_pred],mu)
    beta_function=function([y_pred],beta)
    id_function=function([y_true],x)
    likelihood = .5*(beta_function(y_pred)*(id_function(y_true)-mu_function(y_pred))**2)-T.log(beta_function(y_pred)/(2*np.pi))
    l_func = function([y_true,y_pred], likelihood)
    return(l_func(y_true,y_pred))
```